# How to set up a random letter generator in Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am attempting to set up a series of buttons to display random letters in a row using Vue 3 Composition API. In the setup function, I created 4 separate arrays with a series of letters. The letters are then randomized using random functions, then returned to the screen using a function called by the onBeforeMount life cycle hook. The result is that the letters on each button are updated every time the page is refreshed. Currently, my code is set up to initialize each letter constant to an empty ref, like so:

```
    const letterDisplayOne = ref('')
    const letterDisplayTwo = ref('')
    const letterDisplayThree = ref('')
    const letterDisplayFour = ref('')
```

To me, the above seemed messy. So I instead tried refactoring so that the constants were consolidated to one ref method:

```
const { letterDisplayOne, letterDisplayTwo, letterDisplayThree, letterDisplayFour } = ref('')
```

However, when I set up the constants and empty ref this way I was then prevented from unpacking the .value of each of those constants when they were referenced in subsequent functions. My question: is it possible to consolidate multiple groups of constants in a way that doesn't prevent unpacking the .values (or other errors)?

Here is my full code:

Template

```
<template>
  <div div class="flex justify-center">
    <button @click="handleClick">Click for Audio</button>
    <button>{{ letterDisplayOne }}</button>
    <button>{{ letterDisplayTwo }}</button>
    <button>{{ letterDisplayThree }}</button>
    <button>{{ letterDisplayFour }}</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue' 
import { onBeforeMount } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'Button',
  components: {},
  setup() {

    const letterDisplayOne = ref('')
    const letterDisplayTwo = ref('')
    const letterDisplayThree = ref('')
    const letterDisplayFour = ref('')
    const letterArrayOne = ref(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
    const letterArrayTwo = ref(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
    const letterArrayThree = ref(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
    const letterArrayFour = ref(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
    const chosenOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArrayOne.value.length)
    const chosenTwo = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArrayTwo.value.length)
    const chosenThree = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArrayThree.value.length)
    const chosenFour = Math.floor(Math.random() * letterArrayFour.value.length)

    const handleletterArray = () => {
      letterDisplayOne.value = letterArrayOne.value[chosenOne]
      letterDisplayTwo.value = letterArrayTwo.value[chosenTwo]
      letterDisplayThree.value = letterArrayThree.value[chosenThree]
      letterDisplayFour.value = letterArrayFour.value[chosenFour]
    }

    onBeforeMount(() => {
      handleletterArray()
    })

    return {  
    letterDisplayOne,
    letterDisplayTwo,
    letterDisplayThree,
    letterDisplayFour,
    letterArrayOne,
    letterArrayTwo,
    letterArrayThree,
    letterArrayFour, 
    handleletterArray, 
    onBeforeMount, 
    chosenOne,
    chosenTwo,
    chosenThree,
    chosenFour 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be:

```
const { letterDisplayOne, … } = toRefs(reactive({ letterDisplayOne: '', … }));
```

Refs are specifically useful for two common cases. The first is when a value needs to be passed by reference as an object. The second is that a value isn't consistent and cannot be represented as reactive object, while ref value can be anything.

None of these cases are applicable here, so there's no practical benefit from using separate refs. It can be just:

```
const letters = reactive({ one: '', … });
```